# Adding a tag to one item instead of all items?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to add tags to just one student, but I'm running into an issue where it adds the inputed tag to all the students. Everything else such as fetching from the URL is works fine.

Adding only part of the snippet to prevent any copying and pasting

```
const [ students, setStudents ] = useState([])
const [ tags, setTags ] = useState([])

const addTags = (event) => {
    if (event.key === 'Enter' && event.target.value !== '') {
      setTags([...tags, event.target.value])
      event.target.value = ''
    }
  }
  
if(!isLoaded) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>
  } else {
    return (
      <div className='__main'>
        <ul className='__list'>
          {students.map((student) => (
            <li className='__student' key={student.id}>
              <img src={student.pic} alt='student' />
              <div className='__student-info'>
                <h1>{student.firstName} {student.lastName}</h1>
                <div className='__student-details'>
                  <p>Email: {student.email}</p>
                  <p>Company: {student.company}</p>
                  <p>Skill: {student.skill}</p>
                  <p>
                    Average: {student.grades.reduce((a, b) => parseInt(b) + a, 0) / student.grades.map((grade) => grade).length}%
                  </p>
                <div className='__student-tags'>
                  <ul className='__student-tags-list'>
                    {tags.map((tag, index) => (
                      <li className='__student-tag-item' key={index}>
                        <span>{tag}</span>
                      </li>
                    ))}
                  </ul>
                  <input
                    className='__student-tag-input'
                    type='text'
                    placeholder='Add a tag'
                    onKeyPress={(event) => addTags(event)}
                    autoFocus
                  />
                </div>
              </div>
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    )
  }
```

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise to explain in more detail what your component does and how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding all tags for all students to the single `tags` state array with `setTags([...tags, event.target.value])`. Instead of using a separate `tags` state you probably want to add a `tags` array for each student in the `students` array. Use the `student.id` property to update the appropriate student's tags.

Example:

Update the `addTags` handler to take a student id and return a callback to receive the `onKeyPress` event. Map the previous `students` state to a new array and for the matching student by `id` shallow copy the `student` object and append the new `tag` to a `tags` array. Note that this is a curried function that closes over the student `id` value in callback scope.

```
const addTags = id => (event) => {
  const { value: tag } = event.target;
  if (event.key === 'Enter' && tag) {
    setStudents(students => students.map(
      student => student.id === id
        ? {
          ...student,
          tags: [...(student.tags || []), tag],
        }
        : student
    ));
    event.target.value = '';
  }
};
```

Map a `student.tags` array instead of the standalone `tags` state. Pass the `student.id` to the `addTags` handler.

```
<div className='__main'>
  <ul className='__list'>
    {students.map((student) => (
      <li className='__student' key={student.id}>
        <img src={student.pic} alt='student' />
        <div className='__student-info'>
          <h1>{student.firstName} {student.lastName}</h1>
          <div className='__student-details'>
            ...
            <div className='__student-tags'>
              <ul className='__student-tags-list'>
                {student.tags?.map((tag, index) => ( // <-- map student.tags array
                  <li className='__student-tag-item' key={index}>
                    <span>{tag}</span>
                  </li>
                ))}
              </ul>
              <input
                className='__student-tag-input'
                type='text'
                placeholder='Add a tag'
                onKeyPress={addTags(student.id)} // <-- pass student.id
                autoFocus
              />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
    ))}
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: This worked, thank you so much! Can you clarify how students.tags?.map works vs just students.tags.map? I've noticed it crashes with just students.tags.map.

Comment: @EricDaoNguyen Ah, it seems I've assumed, correctly, that your `students` data elements *don't* include any `tags` property. The [Optional Chaining Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) (`?.`) allows access into potentially null/undefined properties without throwing an exception. `student.tags?.map` is equivalent to `student.tags && student.tags.map`, in other words, `student.tags` needs to be truthy in order to get to `.map` function.

Comment: @EricDaoNguyen `student.tags.map` alone crashed because `student.tags` is undefined before the `addTags` handler was able to inject a `tags` property into the `students` data.